# Creating Stored Procedure takes very long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure spVerhoogPrijzen1
    @artikelcategorie varchar(128),
    @ingangsdatum date
as 
    begin transaction

    update p
    set prijs = prijs * 1.1
    from artikelprijs p 
    join artikel a on a.artikelnr = p.artikelnr
    join artikelcategorie c on c.catcode = a.catcode
    where c.catomschrijving like @artikelcategorie
      and p.begindatum >= @ingangsdatum

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin
        rollback
        Raiserror('Je hebt iets fouts ingevuld', 16, 1)
    end
    commit
```

But when I run it, it takes forever to create the procedure. I stopped it after 15 minutes.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Artikel contains:

```
401 Kaviaar                 lux
402 Ganzenlever             lux
403 Vruchtenyoghurt Aardbei zuv
404 Volle Yoghurt           zuv
405 Magere Kwark            zuv
```

Artikelcategorie contains:

```
bio biologische artikelen  
lux luxe artikelen van de traitteur  
zuv zuivelartikelen
```

Artikelprijs contains:

```
401 21.50   2012-01-01  2099-12-31  
402 38.95   2012-01-01  2012-12-31  
402 39.95   2013-01-01  2013-10-31  
402 37.00   2013-11-01  2099-12-31  
403 16.25   2012-01-01  2013-07-31
```

Comment: Nicer code styling helps to see the obvious.  But, ah, are you sure you have all the right 'END' where they belong.. It' been awhile but it appears you're missing one.

Comment: Perhaps blocking. Run `sp_who2` to see if that's the case.

Comment: Have you tried another time maybe some other transaction blocking this query when you were executing? Try to run the tables using select query outside of SP and check still it's taking too much time.

Comment: @muren Do you pass `@artikelcategorie` as `%something%`? If yes then your entire query is not SARGable

Comment: @SathiyaKumar I have run sp_who 2 and the status is suspended.

Comment: @lad2025 I don't add % to my parameters

Comment: Let's be clear.  Are you asking about create the procedure (not run the procedure)?   Your words are "it takes forever to create the procedure".

Comment: @paparazzo I'm still creating the procedure. Not running it.

Comment: Try creating a real real simple procedure to see if you are just plain getting blocked.   Did you try my answer?

Comment: @paparazzo I've tried your answer, but it's the same issue. When I try to create a simple procedure it works. When I import the database into system databases --> master my procedure works however

Comment: @muren, so the `BlkBy` in the sp_who2 output is empty?

Comment: @DanGuzman, I can't find it anymore. Cause strangely it's working fine now after the solution from Emdad. (My SQL is working fine)

Comment: @muren, please edit your data for clearly understand.

Comment: @Emdad, Like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the following procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_VerhoogPrijzen1
    @artikelcategorie1 varchar(128),
    @ingangsdatum date
AS 
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #artikelprijs  (artikelnr INT,prijs DECIMAL(18,2),begindatum DATETIME)
    CREATE TABLE #artikel (artikelnr INT,name VARCHAR(100),catcode VARCHAR(10))
    CREATE TABLE #artikelcategorie (catcode VARCHAR(10),catomschrijving varchar(128))

    INSERT INTO #artikelprijs VALUES
    (401,21.50,'2012-01-01'), 
    (402,38.95,'2012-01-01'),
    (402,39.95,'2013-01-01'),
    (401,37.00,'2013-11-01'),
    (403,16.25,'2012-01-01')

    INSERT INTO #artikel VALUES
    (401,'Kaviaar','lux'),
    (402,'Ganzenlever','lux'),
    (403,'Vruchtenyoghurt Aardbei','zuv'),
    (404,'Volle Yoghurt','zuv'),
    (405,'Magere Kwark','zuv')


    INSERT INTO #artikelcategorie VALUES
    ('bio','biologische artikelen'),  
    ('lux','luxe artikelen van de traitteur'),  
    ('zuv','zuivelartikelen')  

    UPDATE P
    SET P.prijs = P.prijs * 1.1
    FROM #artikelprijs P
    INNER JOIN #artikel A on A.artikelnr = p.artikelnr
    INNER JOIN #artikelcategorie C on C.catcode = A.catcode
    WHERE c.catomschrijving like @artikelcategorie1 AND P.begindatum >= @ingangsdatum

    SELECT P.* FROM #artikelprijs P
    INNER JOIN #artikel A on A.artikelnr = p.artikelnr
    INNER JOIN #artikelcategorie C on C.catcode = A.catcode
    WHERE c.catomschrijving like @artikelcategorie1 AND P.begindatum >= @ingangsdatum

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        Raiserror('Je hebt iets fouts ingevuld', 16, 1)
    END

    SELECT * FROM #artikelprijs
    DROP TABLE #artikelprijs
    DROP TABLE #artikel
    DROP TABLE #artikelcategorie
END

--EXEC USP_VerhoogPrijzen1 'zuivelartikelen', '2012-01-01'
```

According to your join condition, one row is affected which catcode is 403 and value is 16.25. After update this value has changed to 17.88. Please check and Thanks.

Comment: Okay, this created right away. However does it update the original table? Cause I don't see a change.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data of those three table? Or you can insert sample data of those tree temp table and try to run.

Comment: Edited my message.

Comment: Thanks for providing data. But I dont have permission to edit your message.

Comment: @muren, I have updated my query. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a transaction for a single statement.

Give this a try:

```
Create Procedure spVerhoogPrijzen1
    @artikelcategorie varchar(128),
    @ingangsdatum date
as 
    update p
    set prijs = prijs * 1.1
    from artikelprijs p 
    join artikel a on a.artikelnr = p.artikelnr
    join artikelcategorie c on c.catcode = a.catcode
    where c.catomschrijving like @artikelcategorie
      and p.begindatum >= @ingangsdatum

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin
        Raiserror('Je hebt iets fouts ingevuld', 16, 1)
    end
```

Comment: SPs should not, in my opinion, have commits in them anyway.  They have no way of knowing the context in which they are called so should not assume they are the top of the call tree. Let the caller decide the transaction scope.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, I think it depends on the use case. The main thing to avoid is an explicit transaction in both the client and proc.